# Winforms UltraGrid Infragistics grouping by two columns

Tags: vb.net, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I’m working on a WinForms vb.net app where you can see a Grid like the one shown in the picture attached and what I need to do is to group by the first two columns (“Grupo” and “Area”).

As you can see in the picture my SQL select statement returns many same “Grupo” and “Area” with different “identificacion” (the last visible column) and the way I would need to present it is more or less the same you can currently see in the picture but with something like for example a + sign at a side which when you press it expands and shows all the complete list of rows and columns (ungrouped) but one row for every different “identificacion”.

I’ve managed to do an approach with SortedColums with the next:

```
ulgListaSel.DisplayLayout.ViewStyleBand = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ViewStyleBand.OutlookGroupBy

Dim band As UltraGridBand = ulgListaSel.DisplayLayout.Bands(0)
Dim sortedColumns As SortedColumnsCollection = band.SortedColumns
sortedColumns.Add("c_area", False, True)
sortedColumns.Add("c_grupo", False, True)
```

but data is not being displayed the way I’m looking for.

What I get with the code below is shown in figure 2 but you will see that only "Area" colum is shown before expanding and as a default I need all columns with same value to be shown (everythings except "identificacion").

By the way, I’m using UltraGrid v14.2

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you here correctly, you would like to have a group for each row, because the only differences are in the "identificacion" column values? Or you would like to see all the values in the groupByRow, except the "identification", and having only one group?

In the second case you would end up with only one group having the all of the column values there.

In both cases you could create and add a new unbound column in the InitializeLayout event of your UltraGrid, using the root band (0) columns collection, afterwards in the IntializeRow event populate the values of that new column based on your requirements, either using the values of all of the cells (to end up with the same number of groups as the number of differences in the "identificacion" column), or concatenating the values of all of the columns, without the ones in "identificacion", which would end up with a single group only at end.

Also once you do that, you would have to use again the InitializeLayout event of your UltraGrid, and Group by the UltraGrid, by the newly populated Unbound column, by adding it to Sorted Columns, using the same approach that was used for adding the other columns there.